# Foreign key as primary key doesn't work if FK table has composite primary key (FK is not part of the composite)

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, primary-key, foreign-key-relationship, composite-primary-key

two tables, created using these scripts:

```
create table user_auth
(
    username varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    password varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    user_id varchar(36) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(username, password)
)engine=innodb;

create table user
(
    user_id varchar(36) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(user_id),
    FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES user_auth(user_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
)engine=innodb;
```

I get the error:
    Can't create table 'xxx.user' (errno: 150)

A foreign key error.

**IF instead I do this (remove foreign key constraint but still reference user_auth):**

```
create table user_auth
(
    username varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    password varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    user_id varchar(36) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(username, password)
)engine=innodb;

create table user
(
    user_id varchar(36) NOT NULL REFERENCES user_auth(user_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    PRIMARY KEY(user_id),
)engine=innodb;
```

Everything is just peachy, ***BUT*** I can insert a user_id into the user table without having a corresponding key in user_auth, which puts a hole in my referential integrity.

**Now for kicks say I do this (remove composite key and make user_id a primary key in user_auth):**

```
create table user_auth
(
    user_id varchar(36) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(username, password)
)engine=innodb;

create table user
(
    user_id varchar(36) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(user_id),
    FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES user_auth(user_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
)engine=innodb;
```

This also works, though I do not have the username/password composite to ensure uniqueness.

I have a feeling I'm missing something pretty key in how MySQL works. Please enlighten.

Thanks for your time!

**UPDATE**

In the article  ypercube linked in their answer, point three mentions the ***order*** of the PK and corresponding FK **must** be the same. If I add `user_id` as a PK in `user_auth` in the following order, the script works:

```
create table user_auth
(
    username varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    password varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    user_id varchar(36) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(user_id, username, password)
)engine=innodb;

create table user
(
    user_id varchar(36) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(user_id),
    FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES user_auth(user_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
)engine=innodb;
```

So I can still `SELECT` and such, but now I can't make duplicate username/password combos and thus each account will be unique since a username/password/user_id record must exist before I can insert user data.

Comment: Do you need the composite PK in `user_auth`?

Comment: I could have just the username be the PK. I tried that but still no go.

Comment: Your last try should work if you had `PRIMARY KEY(user_id)` in table `user_auth` (you say you did but the code is different. You could also add a `UNIQUE KEY (username, password)` or just a `UNIQUE KEY (username)`, depending on what you need.

Comment: You're right about that, turns out it's the order. I'll post it as an update.

Comment: Another question. Why 2 different tables and not one? And if you mean to have more than one authentications for a user, then your FK is on the wrong direction. It should be on `user_auth` and referencing table `user`.

Comment: That's what I figured at first too, but then I have to make entries into `user` before I make `user_auth`, which isn't bad, unless of course I want to see if a username/password combo already exists. Then I have to check in my PHP code. Instead, having `user` be the child means that the username/password combo must be available before I can make a user account, so it's covered in MySQL by referential integrity. Also, I would rather reference user data by userid, I only really use username/password to validate logins.

Comment: No, No, No! You **do not** want `PRIMARY KEY(user_id, username, password)`. Make that `PRIMARY KEY(user_id), UNIQUE KEY (username, password)`

Comment: An FK must reference either a Primary Key or a Unique key. Even if MySQL allows otherwise, it is **not recommended**. Read in MySQL docs: **[`FOREIGN KEY` Constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)**, where it states: ***"Deviation from SQL standards: A FOREIGN KEY constraint that references a non-UNIQUE key is not standard SQL."***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Point 3 in  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html says everything. So if I add `user_id` as a PK in `user_auth` (I thought I mentioned I tried this, but it seems I missed the script example), then it still might not work:

```
create table user_auth
(
    username varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    password varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    user_id varchar(36) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(username, password, user_id) -- <== DOES NOT WORK
)engine=innodb;

create table user
(
    user_id varchar(36) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(user_id),
    FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES user_auth(user_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
)engine=innodb;
```

**But, if I change the order around...**

```
create table user_auth
(
    username varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    password varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    user_id varchar(36) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(user_id, username, password) -- <== WORKS!
)engine=innodb;

create table user
(
    user_id varchar(36) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(user_id),
    FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES user_auth(user_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
)engine=innodb;
```

Because in order to user the PK of user_auth as an FK, they must be in the **same order as indices**, (comment if I am misunderstanding something).

**But in terms of table design we still have an issue, the composite key means I could have duplicate user_ids in user_auth, so a smarter design would be:**

```
create table user_auth
(
    username varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    password varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    user_id varchar(36) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(user_id),
    UNIQUE KEY(username) -- <== I should allow duplicate passwords, so just usernames should be               unique
)engine=innodb;

create table user
(
    user_id varchar(36) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(user_id),
    FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES user_auth(user_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
)engine=innodb;
```

**Much better**

The main take-away is that the **order** of your composite keys **matters!**

Comment: Read the answer by Bill Karwin in this question: [Mysql and FK's Problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7367485/mysql-and-fks-problem/7367616#7367616), especially the last paragraph that says *"I feel the need to emphasize the last point. You **will** get **anomalous data** if you define foreign keys to non-uniquely indexed columns in the parent. This will probably cause your queries to report rows multiple time when you do joins. **You should not use this behavior of InnoDB; you should define foreign keys only to parent columns that are unique."***

Comment: "You should not use this behavior of InnoDB; you should define foreign keys only to parent columns that are unique." user_id is uniquely indexed? As a Guid? Or are we talking about something else?

Comment: The "parent" column is `user_auth(user_id)` which is not unique in your code. It's only the first column of a unique index.

Comment: Ah! So by allowing the username, password, user_id to be a composite, it allows me to (potentially) have duplicate user_id's as long as their username and password are different? Which is what your comment above fixes by having PRIMARY KEY(user_id) and UNIQUE KEY(username,password) (which I'll probably just have that be UNIQUE(username), I should allow duplicate passwords). Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the point. And then (if there are duplicate ids with different username and/or password), the rows in `user` table that are referring to this (duplicate) id would actually reference more than one row in `user_auth`. And that is dangerous.

Comment: Excellent, I'll mention it in my answer!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
create table user_auth
(
    username varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    password varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    user_auth_id varchar(36) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(username, password)
)engine=innodb;

create table user
(
    user_id varchar(36) NOT NULL,
    user_username varchar(36) NOT NULL, 
    user_pass varchar(36) NOT NULL, 
    INDEX(user_username, user_pass),
    PRIMARY KEY(user_id),
    FOREIGN KEY(user_username, user_pass) REFERENCES user_auth(username, password) ON DELETE CASCADE
)engine=innodb;
```

Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

Comment: That reference helped, the issue revolves around point three:

InnoDB requires indexes on foreign keys and referenced keys so that foreign key checks can be fast and not require a table scan. In the referencing table, there must be an index where the foreign key columns are listed as the first columns in the same order. Such an index is created on the referencing table automatically if it does not exist. This index might be silently dropped later, if you create another index that can be used to enforce the foreign key constraint. index_name, if given, is used as described previously.

Comment: So I can maintain my table structure if I add user_id as a primary key in user_auth, and order it as follows: PRIMARY KEY (user_id, username, password), which follows the strictures of point three as both keys (the PK in user_auth and FK in user) are in the same order.